# react native package not working when installing to another project

Tags: react-native, npm-package

When i install my test react native package to another project then project crashes and nothing see in console.
I install using "yarn add path/to/package"

**react native test package**

package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "project-react-mvc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "REACT MVC Library",
  "main": "lib/commonjs/index",
  "module": "lib/module/index",
  "react-native": "src/index.js",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "src",
    "lib",
    "android",
    "ios",
    "cpp",
    "*.podspec",
    "!lib/typescript/example",
    "!ios/build",
    "!android/build",
    "!android/gradle",
    "!android/gradlew",
    "!android/gradlew.bat",
    "!android/local.properties",
    "!**/__tests__",
    "!**/__fixtures__",
    "!**/__mocks__",
    "!**/.*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\"",
    "prepack": "bob build",
    "release": "release-it",
    "example": "yarn --cwd example",
    "bootstrap": "yarn example && yarn install"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "repository": "https://github.com/kriit24/project-react-mvc",
  "author": "Kuno Vaik <kuno@projectpartner.ee> (https://github.com/kriit24)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/kriit24/project-react-mvc/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/kriit24/project-react-mvc#readme",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.2",
    "@evilmartians/lefthook": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.2",
    "@release-it/conventional-changelog": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "0.70.0",
    "commitlint": "^17.0.2",
    "del-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-builder-bob": "^0.20.0",
    "release-it": "^15.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.21"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 16.0.0"
  },
  "packageManager": "^yarn@1.22.15",
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/example/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/lib/"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native(-.*)?|@react-native(-community)?|@rneui|expo(-.*)?|@expo(-.*)?/.)/)"
    ]
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ]
  },
  "release-it": {
    "git": {
      "commitMessage": "chore: release ${version}",
      "tagName": "v${version}"
    },
    "npm": {
      "publish": true
    },
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },
    "plugins": {
      "@release-it/conventional-changelog": {
        "preset": "angular"
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "@react-native-community",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": [
        "error",
        {
          "quoteProps": "consistent",
          "singleQuote": true,
          "tabWidth": 2,
          "trailingComma": "es5",
          "useTabs": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "node_modules/",
    "lib/"
  ],
  "prettier": {
    "quoteProps": "consistent",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": false
  },
  "react-native-builder-bob": {
    "source": "src",
    "output": "lib",
    "targets": [
      "commonjs",
      "module"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.5.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

src/index.js file

```
import { ProjectReact, App } from './component/project.react';
import Loader from './helper/loader';

const Project = {
  React: ProjectReact,
};

export { Project, App, Loader };
```

src/helper/loader.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import css from '../assets/style';

export default function Loader(props) {
  return null;
}
```

src/assets/style.js file

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';

const css = StyleSheet.create({
});

export default css;
```

when i comment out in "src/helper/loader.js" line "import css from '../assets/style';" then everything works, othervise not, what can be wrong in "src/assets/style.js" file ?

when i run jest test then everything is ok.
But whn i install and import then app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

yarn add project - just does not work for testing purposes.

instead publish npm package, install to test application and then test in there.